# change all image sources jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I want to change all image sources if they fail to load. Some companies block access to dropbox so I like to use an alternative link for images. Also, I don't want to modify images and css files. My code does work for the first image but makes every image source the same. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<img  src="img/a.png" alt="img1"/>
 <img  src="img/b.png" alt="img2"/>

</body>

<script>

var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://dropbox.com/favicon.ico";
if (image.height < 0) {

var imgsrc = $('img').attr('src');

var imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(imgsrc.lastIndexOf("img/"));
imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(4);
var imgalt = imgsrc1.substr(4,imgsrc.length - 4);

var imgsrc2 ='t/' + imgsrc1;
$('img').attr('src',imgsrc2);
$('img').attr('alt',imgalt);    

    } else {


var imgsrc = $('img').attr('src');

var imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(imgsrc.lastIndexOf("img/"));
imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(4);
var imgalt = imgsrc1.substr(4,imgsrc.length - 4);

var imgsrc2 ='http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxxx/img/' + imgsrc1;
$('img').attr('src',imgsrc2);
$('img').attr('alt',imgalt);    

    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to do the same procedure for all the images, I think your code only works for the first one. Specifically the line `var imgsrc = $('img').attr('src');`.

Try something like this inside the else-clause:

```
$('img').each(function() {
     var $img = $(this);
     var imgsrc = $img.attr('src');

     var imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(imgsrc.lastIndexOf("img/"));
     imgsrc1     = imgsrc.substr(4);
     var imgalt  = imgsrc1.substr(4,imgsrc.length - 4);

     var imgsrc2 ='http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxxx/img/' + imgsrc1;
     $img.attr('src',imgsrc2);
     $img.attr('alt',imgalt);
}
```

It can also be noteworthy that Dropbox has a transfer limit in, at least, bandwidth per day (don't know if there is a max hit count per day though): https://www.dropbox.com/help/45

Comment: Christoffer, I tried for each before but then the entire code stops working. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){

        var imgsrc = $(this).attr('src');

        $(this).load(function(){
            if( $(this).prop('complete') ){

                var imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(imgsrc.lastIndexOf("img/"));
                imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(4);
                var imgalt = imgsrc1.substr(4,imgsrc.length - 4);

                var imgsrc2 ='t/' + imgsrc1;
                $('img').attr('src',imgsrc2);
                $('img').attr('alt',imgalt);

            }else{

                var imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(imgsrc.lastIndexOf("img/"));
                imgsrc1 = imgsrc.substr(4);
                var imgalt = imgsrc1.substr(4,imgsrc.length - 4);

                var imgsrc2 ='http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxxx/img/' + imgsrc1;
                $('img').attr('src',imgsrc2);
                $('img').attr('alt',imgalt);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Sagar, I used your code and it appears all images become the second image and page doesn't stop loading. Thanks for try though.