# Redirect all external http images src paths to one php loader file to have full https content

Tags: php, html, image, .htaccess, redirect

In this case the website is on https but loads in the CMS editor images from external sources via for example http://external-site.com/image.jpg. This gives me the https security error about mixed content.

So, my plan was to redirect all http:// image src's to one file on my server (image_server.php) which loads the image via file_get_contens() and prints it out.

I got that part working. I am able to use images like:

```
<img src="https://cms.website.com/handlers/image_server.php?url=http://external-site.com/images/image.jpg" alt="Image over HTTPS" />
```

And the https page is fully happy with that approach.

But one more step needs to be applied. The image src paths to the external sites need to be redirected to the image_server.php file (and I can't change these paths because it's content of other websites managed by this central CMS).

Where I got stuck is the redirect part in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule (^.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff))$ https://cms.website.com/handlers/image_server.php?url=$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

The image with `src="http://external-site.com/images/image.jpg"` should be picked up by the .htaccess file and automatically redirect to `"https://cms.website.com/handlers/image_server.php?url=http://external-site.com/images/image.jpg"`.

But this isn't happening. So far only the local images are directed to the image_server.php file and the external image stays untouched and still causes the mixed content error.

Please help!

So in short. How do I redirect an image like this:

```
<img src="http://external-site.com/images/image.jpg" />
```

To, this with .htaccess (and without changing the actual content of the page):

```
<img src="https://cms.website.com/handlers/image_server.php?url=http://external-site.com/images/image.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When your browser sees `src="http://external-site.com/...` it will not assume this to be found in `https://cms.website.com/...`. `https://cms.website.com/` will not get any request from the client's browser.

You could add some javascript to automatically replace all image elements and replace the src attribute to what you need, say like using jquery ready function. Here is somewhere you could start from [change all image sources jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031779/change-all-image-sources-jquery)

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking of Javascript as an alternative. But doesn't that change the content of the html? So the editor will save a different path then the original and that would become a problem for this CMS.

Comment: Editor can save the original path. On the view screens (clientside - not CMS side) you can include your javascript to update the links using on-ready. On the otherhand, your view-rendering scripts on the server could also do this before sending the files off to the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately Javascript isn't an option either. Because it's not possible to replace the src paths before the image loads. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167734/is-it-possible-to-change-out-an-image-src-before-the-original-image-loads